# will h57m be compatible with 8gb ddr3 single stick?

Tags: memory, compatibility

I have a GA-h57m usb3.  I Have a 2x2gb ram total of 4.
I want to upgrade to more.
Will my h57m support 8gb ddr3 single stick? 
or do I need to buy a 2x4gb?

Comment: At GIGABYTE support site you have [Memory Support List](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3307#memory%20support%20list) that you could find apart from me... So I'm also downvoting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 8GB of RAM and your motherboard supports Dual Channel mode (Which is safe to say almost all of them do, and yours certainly does), you would want to purchase 2x4GB RAM anyway to get the benefits of this.

[Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Giga-Byte/ga-h57m-usb3) provide a handy list of their compatible RAM with your motherboard which will give you a good indication of what you can use.

Further reading on [multi-channel memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture).

Answer (score 1):

In the technichal specifications for memory for this board, there is only 1 RAM-stick with 4GB tested. That would be the Kingston KHX1600C9D3K3/12GX.

Link to the [Memory Support List](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3307#memory%20support%20list).

There is no 8GB stick which is approved. So take the safe route and get 2x4GB.